# Debugging RadioButtons program in Python

Tags: python, debugging, radio-button, tkinter

I wrote a simple program importing Tkinter just to play with Radio Buttons. I find that I'm getting errors in very, very weird places.

```
 from Tkinter import *

class Application (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):


        Label(self, text = "Select the last book you read.").grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.choice = StringVar() 

        Radiobutton (self,text = "Nausea by Jean-Paul Sartre",variable = self.choice,
                 value = "Wake up. This is a dream. This is all only a test of the emergency broadcasting system.",
                 command = self.update_text).grid (row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        Radiobutton (self,
                 text = "Infinite Jest by David Foster Wallace",
                 variable = self.choice,
                 value = "Because an adult borne without the volition to choose the thoughts that he thinks, is going to get hosed ;)",
                 command = self.update_text).grid (row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        Radiobutton (self,
                 text = "Cat's Cradle by Kurt Vonnegut",
                 variable = self.choice,
                 value = " \"Here we are, trapped in the amber of the moment. There is no why!\" ",
                 command = self.update_text.grid (row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_display = Text (self, width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.txt_display.grid (row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)


    #There is only one choice value - self.choice. That can be "printed."

    def update_text(self):
        message = self.choice.get()
        self.txt_display.delete (0.0, END)
        self.txt_display.insert (0.0, message)

# The Main
root = Tk()
root.title ("The Book Critic One")
root.geometry ("400x400")

app = Application (root)
root.mainloop()
```

I seem to be getting errors in very odd places. One came in the "=" sign in the Label attribution and when I changed it to == when i was playing around, the next one came in the variable part of the RadioButton attributes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Won't be able to respond immediately as I have to leave to work in a bit, but if you do spot where the bugs are, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of things going on here.  I'll just point out the few that I've found quickly looking at this.

For your `Label` you shouldn't have `=` before your parameters...

```
Label = (self, text = "Select the last book you read.").grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

to:

```
Label(self, text = "Select the last book you read.").grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
```

Change all instances of `RadioButton` to `Radiobutton` as that is the actual name of the class in Tkinter.

`choice1`, `choice2`, and `choice3` do not exist in `Application`.

**More Stuff:**

`def create_widgets()` is missing the `self` parameter: `def create_widgets(self)`

Your `update_text()` function isn't working because you're referencing `self.text_display`, I believe you want this to be `self.txt_display` since that is how you defined it previously.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it around, but I am still getting another baffling syntax error with highlight "self". Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427245/debugging-radiobuttons-program-in-python

Comment: sorry to be cumbersome. I updated the code and fixed all the errors that I know of including the bugs with the choice variables. Added self to the parameter of create widgets, and fixed the typo in txt_display. Syntax error still pops up in the same place: "self.txt_display" and "self" is highlighted.

Comment: got it. It was a rogue missing paren. Thanks for all your assistance.