# Debugging RadioButtons program in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):


        Label(self, text = "Select the last book you read.").grid (row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.choice = StringVar() 

        Radiobutton (self,text = "Nausea by Jean-Paul Sartre",variable = self.choice,
                 value = "Wake up. This is a dream. This is all only a test of the emergency broadcasting system.",
                 command = self.update_text).grid (row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)

        Radiobutton (self,
                 text = "Infinite Jest by David Foster Wallace",
                 variable = self.choice,
                 value = "Because an adult borne without the volition to choose the thoughts that he thinks, is going to get hosed ;)",
                 command = self.update_text).grid (row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)

        Radiobutton (self,
                 text = "Cat's Cradle by Kurt Vonnegut",
                 variable = self.choice,
                 value = " \"Here we are, trapped in the amber of the moment. There is no why!\" ",
                 command = self.update_text.grid (row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

        self.txt_display = Text (self, width = 40, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.txt_display.grid (row = 6, column = 0, sticky = W)


    #There is only one choice value - self.choice. That can be "printed."

    def update_text(self):
        message = self.choice.get()
        self.txt_display.delete (0.0, END)
        self.txt_display.insert (0.0, message)

# The Main
root = Tk()
root.title ("The Book Critic One")
root.geometry ("400x400")

app = Application (root)
root.mainloop()
```

I keep getting a Syntax Error in the self.text_display_delete line which I can't seem to lose.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the previous line - I only count one closing parenthesis, while you should have two:

```
 Radiobutton (self,
                 text = "Cat's Cradle by Kurt Vonnegut",
                 variable = self.choice,
                 value = " \"Here we are, trapped in the amber of the moment. There is no why!\" ",
                 command = self.update_text.grid (row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)) #<-- Missing that second paren
```

Usually if one line looks clean, the syntax error is on the previous line(s), and 99% of the time it's a missing paren.

Comment: That's why I tend to put the closing parenthesis on its own line when doing multiline object calls. Also, based on his other `Radiobutton`s, it'd be [...]`self.update_text).grid`[...]